# Put dynamic Javascript in header after doing operations

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-head

I want to write a plugin that enables a function to be put in my theme in various places. Then I would like to collect the parameters called and generate a Javascript and put it into my site `<head>`.

For instance, my theme would be:

```
<?php
get header();
?>
<div>
     <?php myFuncion("foo"); ?>
</div>
<manyotherdivs>
       ...
</manyotherdivs>
<aside>
     <?php myFunction("bar"); ?>
</aside>
 .... and so on
```

Then I would like to generate this JS:

```
<script>
var params = ["foo", "bar", "baz", ...];
</script>
```

I can collect the parameters by using a class and a static property, but it seems that they will be ignored in the `wp_header` hook, returning an empty array.

Comment: The only solution is output buffering, which I always like to avoid - is there no possibility of adding the JS to the end of the document? Can you be a bit more specific about your goal/why you need the JS in the head - this will help avoid an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic sadly, it's a requirement I have to fulfill for a marketing team.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic and I hate manipulating the buffer too. (Plus, +1 for the _XY problem_, finally I have found a suitable name for my usual way of answering many online help requests :D)

Comment: Well, buffer if it is then ;) Are you happy to carry on coding or do you want some pointers?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Nope, I can do by myself. Thank you anyway for offering your help :)